# Adding data to worksheet where unique identifier accumulates

Tags: excel, vba

I had a mate of mine create a VBA script for me for a rather large Excel file containing football player game records.

The file currently has around 7000 player names over 190000 odd rows and each player is granted a unique PID (PlayerID).  So a player with 10 games played will have 10 rows with one unique PID.

The script goes off to a website, copies player data and pastes it to the end of my excel worksheet called (Goals).  When this data is added to the worksheet if a player matched on surname and firstname already exists, the PID will be populated with that players PID.  If, in the data being added from the website, the player does not already exist a new unique number is to be given to this player.

For example:

The Player Fred SMITH PID=1234 already exists, any new record for him will receive the PID of 1234.

A new player Joe BLOGGS is added via the script the PID for him shall be the highest existing PID + 1. So if Fred SMITH has the highest PID then Joe BLOGGS would then be assigned the PID of 1235.

The script works well until a new player is added.
Data before import:

```
PID | surname | firstname | Game |
1233| Jones   | Mark      | 1
1234| Smith   | Fred      | 2
```

Expected after import - Joe Blogs New player

```
PID | surname | firstname | Game |
1233| Jones   | Mark      | 1
1234| Smith   | Fred      | 2
1235| Bloggs  | Joe       | 3
1234| Smith   | Fred      | 3
```

Actual after import - Joe Blogs New player

```
PID | surname | firstname | Game |
1233| Jones   | Mark      | 1
1234| Smith   | Fred      | 2
1235| Bloggs  | Joe       | 3
1236| Smith   | Fred      | 3
```

I can see why this happens as the script says add 1 in column A, but how can I change it so it adds 1 to the highest number in column A rather than the number on the row above?

Here's the script:

```
For d = 1 To 300000
    If Worksheets("Goals").Range("G" & CStr(d)).Value = surname Then

        If Worksheets("Goals").Range("H" & CStr(d)).Value = firstname Then
            PID = Worksheets("Goals").Range("A" & CStr(d)).Value
            ID = Worksheets("Goals").Range("B" & CStr(d - 1)).Value + 1
            Exit For
        Else:
            If Worksheets("Goals").Range("H" & CStr(d)).Value = "" Then
                PID = Worksheets("Goals").Range("A" & CStr(d - 1)).Value + 1
                ID = Worksheets("Goals").Range("B" & CStr(d - 1)).Value + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Else:

        If Worksheets("Goals").Range("A" & CStr(d)).Value = "" Then
            PID = Worksheets("Goals").Range("A" & CStr(d - 1)).Value + 1
            ID = Worksheets("Goals").Range("B" & CStr(d - 1)).Value + 1
            Exit For
        End If

    End If
Next d
```

Comment: If you are going to have to check for each new entry's previous record (e.g. [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED)) on two fields then either match a previous record or create a new PID depending on the outcome, your imports are going to slow down appreciably. Is there no way to bring the PID in with the import?

Comment: The imports are already very slow - the PID is not able to be imported as this is a unique number I've generated in my worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of other optimizations you would probably benefit from making to your script, leaving aside anything else - you're accessing the Object layer a LOT which will slow things down.

As for calculating the PID quickly, there's a number of good ways to do it. My personal favourite (because it minimizes worksheet layer access) would be to build a dictionary of existing PIDs before you do anything else. If you're only importing say, 20 records, that might take an appreciable amount of time, but otherwise, the ability to use `.HasKey(PID)` methods will save you a LOT of time. Dictionaries are great, especially in languages like VBA.

Side note: What you *really* want is a primary key in a database. For all that Access gets a lot of flac for being too easy to use wrong, it is *probably* a better tool for this kind of thing than Excel.

Anyway, I'll throw in an optimized script in a few minutes, but in the mean time, you might want to look at using something like

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Goals").Range("A1:A30000"))
```

when you're after the highest number in a range...

Comment: This spreadsheet is then copied manually over to a csv file then imported into a MySQL database (rather than Access) - I was thinking would it be easier/better to import the data into MySQL database and have the PID calculated in there rather than in Excel?

Comment: MYSQL will definitely be better suited to assigning IDs. You'll probably need a couple of tables - one for player and id, and one for their games - where ideally you'd set a unique constraint on `(surname, firstname)`, have the PID calculated by a `COUNTER` primary key (or MYSQL equivalent). You'd calculate what new players you needed to add by a left join against the players table, filter using `players.[pid] = null`, and then insert the results. 2 queries and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

While a *helper column* that combined the *firstname* and *surname* would speed up general lookup operations, creating a virtual one in a Scripting.Dictionary might be the best for your import operation.

> To use a Scripting.Dictionary you will need to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Your code sample looks like it is walking through 300K rows for each new imported player. You will be able to see where my understanding of your supplied snippet breaks down.

```
    Dim d As Long, lID As Long, lPID As Long, sPLYR As String
    Dim surname As String, firstname As String
    Dim dPLYRs As New Scripting.Dictionary

    dPLYRs.CompareMode = TextCompare

    'populate scripting dictionary
    With Worksheets("Goals")
        lID = Application.Max(.Range("B:B"))
        lPID = Application.Max(.Range("A:A"))
        For d = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            sPLYR = .Cells(d, "G").Value & Chr(124) & .Cells(d, "H").Value
            If Len(sPLYR) > 1 And Not dPLYRs.Exists(sPLYR) Then
                dPLYRs.Add Key:=sPLYR, Item:=.Cells(d, "A").Value
            ElseIf Len(sPLYR) > 1 And dPLYRs.Exists(sPLYR) Then
                'repair broken PIDs
                .Cells(d, "A") = dPLYRs.Item(sPLYR)
            End If
        Next d
    End With


    'this is where your sample code loses me. I have no idea where surname and firstname come from
    'you probably need a loop to cycle through the imported names
    'you have a unique index of surname & Chr(124) & firstname as the dictionary keys for lookup with the PID as each key's item
    sPLYR = surname & Chr(124) & firstname

    dPLYRs.RemoveAll: Set dPLYRs = Nothing
```

So the dictionary gets populated with all existing players and repairs and PIDs it finds. I cannot determine from what you've offered up what to do past then.

Comment: Just one optimization you could probably make to this quite safely: If you declare the dictionary using `Static dPLYRs As Scripting.Dictionary` instead of `Dim` you can probably populate the dictionary only once (and just keep it updated every time you add a new PID). That way you can skip 300000 instructions for what looks like an inner loop!

Comment: @tobriand - I was thinking the dictionary populating would be a form of pre-processing from existing records and that the loop for new records would take place after that was accomplished. As I've noted, I'm kind of lost as to how it all fits together as it looks to be that the import is walked through assigning *surname* and *firstname* then 300K records are looped through looking for a match for each new *surname* and *firstname*. Need more info from the OP; not enough detail on each step of the import operation.

Comment: Have to say I'm with you there. To me it almost feels like a UDF that's been migrated into something that's looped over. I'm actually tempted to think the code as is should really just use formulae. Only problem is then PIDs may change (even if they remain unique on a per-player basis), but it would probably be faster than what the OP looks like he's doing...

Comment: Thanks guys - would it be better to paste the whole code? It's quite long though.  The surname and firstname come from the website the data is being taken from.

Comment: It's always good to see the whole code, at least if you're going to keep this in VBA (per my comment above, you should really move this into Sql - it'll solve a lot if your issues, most notably of which is Excel and more than about 100k lines of data is dog slow). I think both Jeeped and I kinda get the impression there's a lot you could probably be doing faster than you are. As is, I'd expect your code to take around 10-30 seconds per player on new data, maybe more, and it should really be closer to that for the whole import...

Comment: Thanks guys - i'll take a look at how I can do this in sql - as sounds like it might be a better option.